# Error response from daemon: No such container:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I want to stop container, but I always get this error and facing wired problem.

When I tried to stop container by using `docker-compose down`, the error says in below.

```
$ docker-compose down
Removing network rails_api_default
ERROR: error while removing network: network rails_api_default id ... has active endpoints
```

So, I inspect the network and tried to stop container, however it says there is no container.

```
$ docker network inspect rails_api_default
[
    {
        "Name": "rails_api_default",
        "Id": "e22a339dc85a3d7ce7c60bcab218bd939ff9f5578addb6b1d937b5e9ba1f2e7e",
        ....
        "Containers": {
            "966766894bfb110d4a66963f5af423d9f8e2e33a8259e1cca0ced238e5980196": {
                "Name": "966766894bfb_rails_api_app_1",
                ....
            }
        },
    }
]
```

```
$ docker stop 966766894bfb_rails_api_app_1
Error response from daemon: No such container: 966766894bfb_rails_api_app_1
```

Does anyone know what it `966766894bfb_rails_api_app_1`, and why this happens?

Comment: That is probably an old container that may have failed at some point. Check if you can see it with docker ps -a and remove it with docker rm <containerName>.  If you cannot see it, try docker network disconnect -f <networkName> <networkName>

Comment: Thank you！It worked for me. What I needed was [docker network disconnect]. Could you write your answer to close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably an old container that may have failed at some point. Check if you can see it with `docker ps -a` and remove it with `docker rm <containerName>`. If you cannot see it, try

```
docker network disconnect -f <networkName> <containerName>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `docker network disconnect -f <networkName> <containerName>`?

Comment: You are correct @SeanFeldman. Thanks for catching that. I update the answer